# how to share image of yours choice from image gallery

Tags: android, file, bitmap, menuitem, filepath

My `ImageAdapter` class:

```
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
           R.drawable.p_1,
            R.drawable.p_2,
            R.drawable.p_3,
            R.drawable.p_4,
            R.drawable.p_5
};
```

My `ShareItemMenu` class:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem shareitem= (MenuItem)menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    ShareActionProvider provider = (ShareActionProvider)shareitem.getActionProvider();  
    Bitmap bitmap;
    OutputStream output;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.v); 
    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Share Image Tutorial/");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "v.png"); 
    try {
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");
        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        provider.setShareIntent(share);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

The above code only share 1 image which is `v.png`. I have an array of images and I want to share users choice image.

Kindly suggest me how I can access these images in `File file = new File(dir, "v.png");`

Comment: Um, instead of `R.drawable.v`, use `mThumbIds[index]`, where `index` is whichever one of those drawables that you want.

Comment: i cant access through index.. getting problem